# Android app and website javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, geolocation

I'm trying to build an android app and i'm getting along just fine but i'm having a problem calling a javascript function from the webpage i'm viewing through a webview.

I used this tutorial to get the geolocation in the webview : http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/

Now i want to call this function within my page :

`var t=setTimeout("navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation);",15000);
    function foundLocation(position)
    {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  window.location.href='http://rittenservice.nl/rittensysteem2.php?lat='+lat+'&long='+long+'';
}`

When this function is called it should reload the page with the url so i can save the location with PHP

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

The webview code:

```
public class GeoWebViewActivity extends Activity {
public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("androidurl://")) {
            url = url.replaceAll("androidurl://", "http://");
        }
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
 * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
 */
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo_web_view);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    // Load google.com
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.rittenservice.nl/keypad.php");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the code where you call the variables?

Comment: Wich one do you mean? the php part? I don't think its necesarry because it wont get to that point at all... it wont reload the page

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Add that code before you show your web view. This allows javascript to run in a webview

Comment: It already does that, together with
mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: I updated the original post with the script i have, this was already included. My only problem is that it won't execute the javascript reload from within my webpage

Comment: `mVebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
   }
  });`

Comment: That would be my last resort

Comment: I added it to my script and tried it but it doesn't change a thing.. Thnx for the effort.